# Can a solona token contract handle two tokens instead of one?

Tags: spl-token, rust, spl-token-program, token-2022

I wanna create a solona token that awards people with a 2nd token to their account if they buy during a certain condition. is it possible to create such a token in solona?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do so. You need to first create your 2nd token. You need to send both the token mint accounts in the accounts of the buy function and then you can give conditions when you want to transfer the second token to the buyer.